# Device not applicable for the "main.dart" configuration ,

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I use Android Studio as my IDE in coding Flutter. I was able to create 2 projects before this and it worked absolutely fine. I had to clone a repo from Github. The IDE said to get config. I did that then this happened.
[image]

I already installed sdk .

My android devices android version is 7.0
[image: my android devices android version is 7.0]

Flutter Doctor result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (6 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
    • Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
      flutter config --android-studio-dir=

[!] VS Code
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Tamim Mostafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

I also tried changing the directory an using folder with no white space. I moved the Sdk folder to D:\Android\Sdk. flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (6 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\Sdk
      but Android SDK not found at this location.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
    • Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
      flutter config --android-studio-dir=

[!] VS Code
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Tamim Mostafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

Comment: I had a similar problem as well before and fixed it by creating a new project and just copy those lib files from Github to my project's lib files. My problem in cloning that in Github before is that my settings from the computer I pushed to Github gets copied. This causes a problem because settings of different computers are different.

Comment: yes  tried that. But it My phone didn't showed up there too. I tried that with my previous projects too.

Comment: This might sound totally stupid, but whenever I face such unexpected problems I try restarting the environment first. In this case I simply restarted Android studio after loading new project and the error went way.

Answer (score 65):

I've had the same issue and what worked for me is to re-import the project.

`File > Close Project`, go to the project's directory and delete the `.idea` folder.
Then `File > Open...` and re-open the project.

Open `Project Structure`, you can set the project's SDK with what you have.
[image]

After this, I was able to run `main.dart` with the emulator.
[image]

Comment: worked for me: I deleted the idea folder via the gui, then closed/reopened the project.

Comment: this should be the right answer, looks like if you have imported the project from another device

Comment: I just needed to set the project sdk, it was not set for some reason

Answer (score 37):

It solved my problem:

1. Make sure Flutter plugin is installed in android studio, you can install the plugin from file > setting > plugin
2. choose flutter SDK path from File > setting> Language & Framework > flutter.

[image: For my case the flutter sdk path was D:/flutter]

Answer (score 21):

It took me a while to find `Project` that the others are seeing, it's probably due to the updated version of Android Studio. I found it on `External Libraries` on the left panel and under it, right click on the `Android API (NN) Platform` > `Open Library Settings` > `Project` under `Project Settings` and on the right panel, change the Android API. I had `<No SDK>`, see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This was the magic fix for me, thanks! Slightly odd that no SDK is selected by default

Comment: Tehre's no Open Library Settings when I right click Android API (NN) Platform

Comment: @Dpedrinha - It isn't there anymore but I can see it under File -> Project Structure. Or you can even type "Project Structure" under Help menu textbox. Once you get to that window it would be same as in the picture where you need to correct <No SDK>

Comment: Also be aware, as was said in Gabriel's answer, that you might have to update the same setting for the module, too. This setting goes awry if you replace/upgrade your SDK and I also tend to use a lot of time hunting this down when it happens every few months.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be the problem:

```
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
-> ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\Sdk but Android SDK not found at this location.
```

Since you said that you added the Android SDK to your D directory, you could just add `D:\Android\sdk\tools` and `D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools` to your PATH environment variable. This is how you can add it to your Path enviroment variable: https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables

Comment: @Mominmostafa Good Luck in your future projects.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this problem may have a lot of different symptoms, but for me to be able to run my flutter app in my android device, I had to set the **android SDK** in the `Project Structure` modal.

You can open the `Project Structure` modal by right clicking on the project **root** folder (in the file tree) > `Module Settings` > `Project` and set the `Project SDK`:

Mine is like this:
[image]

If somehow the `Project` tab is disabled or in a weird state, I recommend you to close android studio, delete the project `.iml` file and the `.idea` folder, reopen the project in AS (open existing project) and set the android SDK in the project structure like I've described above. At least this is what I did and it fixed for me, so I hope this answer help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools and check Google USB Driver. Restart Android Studio.
All this worked for me, might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Reading this page helped: by the time I reached the end of this page Android Studio had fully recognised my connected mobile phone (with developer mode enabled) and it was not longer greyed out in the Devices list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Thats warning said "**Android SDK location should not contain whitespace**". There is a whitespace character in `Tamim Mustofa`.

You can move sdk folder to new folder like `D:\Android\Sdk`, where there is no space or other whitespace character in the path.
Change Android Sdk Location address in Android Studio.
and add variabel `ANDROID_HOME` in your Environment Variable: System Variable. with `D:\Android\Sdk` as variable value

Comment: problem stays the same.

Comment: did you make sure all folder and file on the android sdk has moved to new Folder? 
and make sure the previous sdk android folder has been deleted.

Comment: thank you sir. after adding D:\Android\sdk\tools and D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools to your PATH environment variable. it worked. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

type to terminal this below

```
flutter config --android-sdk ANDROID_SDK_PATH
```

Comment: Please elaborate more when writing answers, and also this is dangerous.
This can break your android-sdk param set within flutter - make sure you have ANDROID_SDK_PATH env var in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Some SDK versions of Flutter may cause the problem of not being able to find the device or simulator.You can switch the SDK version to the stable version.
I had a same problem on my Mac with the Flutter version 1.17.4, and it worked after I went back the version to 1.17.3.

Version rollback step:

1.Open the [Flutter GitHub repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter).

2.Click 'master' button to open the switch menu. And the click 'Tags' item.

3.Search the stable version tag(e.g. 1.17.3).

4.Open the tag and click the commits.

5.Copy the top commit id.

6.Run the command 'git reset --hard $(commit id)' in the Flutter directory.

7.Restart the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

File > Invalide caches/restart, work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS and the other answers did not work, try this

```
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no `package` attribute in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file for the `manifest` tag. Adding it solved the problem:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="my.package.name">
```

OR

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="@applicationId">
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to run **Android Studio** as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of problem I was facing so When I was done with Invalid caches/ restart then it automatically detect the main. dart and works fine.

Just give it a try with Invalid Caches/ Restart.

Comment: No need to post two different answers under one question. One good exhaustive answer would be much better.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your Dart SDK and Flutter SDK path setup in the Environment variable setup and inside the setting of the android studio as well.
2. If it is ok then Do Invalid Caches/ Restart the project and Check.

It might be helped. !!!

Answer (score -2):

All you need is Updating the android SDK then restart the IDE.

[image]

That's it.