# Device not applicable for the “main.dart” configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

Before anyone points me to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862570/device-not-applicable-for-the-main-dart-configuration) I would like to mention, that I don't think these are directly related.

As one can see my `flutter doctor -v` command is error free:

```sh
➜  flutter git:(stable) flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/johannes/.flutter-cli/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (5 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/johannes/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Yet I to have the issue of a grayed out emulator device with the message `Device not applicable for the “main.dart” configuration` like this:

[image: grayed out android device]

I can now only start the emulator using the dropdown menu `<no device>` like this:

[image: adding android device]

Interestingly I am then actually able to run my app on the device, while the device is still grayed out:

[image: running emulator]

Flutters hot-reloading feature seems to not work properly though.

I have already added the main folder to the project as suggested [here](https://flutterforum.co/t/emulator-field-grayed-out-not-applicable-for-the-main-dart-configuration/317/7) and I also made sure to change `NO SDK` to `ANDROID API PLATFORM` as suggested in the same link. All dependencies in `Project Structure > Modules` are found by Android Studio. I cloned the Flutter SKD from the stable branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git).

Does anyone have an idea why my setup is behaving this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Device not applicable for the "main.dart" configuration ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862570/device-not-applicable-for-the-main-dart-configuration)

Comment: Nope sadly not. I actually linked that question in the first sentence of my question. I have tried pretty much everything I found on stackoverflow already. ```flutter doctor``` also does not return an error as one can see above. The toolchain does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Close **Android Studio** and Run again as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

**It solved my problem:**

1-  Make sure Flutter plugin is installed in android studio, you can install the plugin from file > setting > plugin

2-  choose flutter SDK path from File > setting> Language & Framework > flutter.
[image: just do like this]

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue before.

- Uninstall Flutter and Dart plugin from Android Studio then reinstall Flutter (Dart will be installed automatically)
- Remove created emulators from AVD Manager and create new one
- Try making new project, and set SDK version same as emulators API version or lower from File > Project Structure...

Hopefully worked for you.