# Not applicable for "main.dart" configuration

Tags: android, api, flutter, emulation

My Android Studio emulator is up and running yet when I run the code, I realize the emulator does not show the code I run.

[image]

I tried out some of the solutions like; Project Structure>Project and I chose the latest Android API there and then to Modules and did same thing, yet did not work.

Instead, after these changes, I got an error message saying IDE Error, that I should report the problem

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880266/5513788 If not, can you run flutter doctor?

Comment: Hi @CodePoet, I'm not using flutter anymore and don't have the previous code now. Thanks for the help though.