# flutter android studio not applicable for the main.dart configuration

Tags: flutter, android-studio

i just installed flutter ,and i created a project ,but when I open android studio and I want to run it on my device I got an error like this [image]

somoene can help me please i spent hours and hours but still got this probleme
[image]

and when i run flutter doctor command i got this [image]

Comment: Please check this post. It might help You:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862570/device-not-applicable-for-the-main-dart-configuration

Comment: i added the variables but stil got this problem

Comment: You may set path to Sdk in Flutter using this command:   flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>

Comment: i tried it they told me Setting "android-sdk" value to "C:\Program".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.

C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: Yes, It will say You may need to .....new settings. Restart Android Studio. Check if it is working or not. If there is any issue, comment below.

Comment: i tried to restart android studio and run it as admin but same error please can you help me ,i spent days of pain

Comment: have you any idea about fixing this ??

Comment: Kindly run flutter doctor and paste the error here.

Comment: unable to locate sdk error i just past a screeen  above

Comment: Kindly locate your Sdk first. Will you please post your Sdk location here in a comment. such as c/:......Sdk.

Comment: can you please check with me in google meet ill pass you the link

Comment: if you want please

Comment: i l share with you my screen

Comment: i reinstalled android studio an now i have no sdk path yet

Comment: okay. you may share it now.

Comment: here is the link in google meet i already shared my sreen https://meet.google.com/nct-hesi-bzg

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this on MacOS by downloading both the Flutter SDK and the Dart SDK and then setting the Flutter SDK and Dark SDK paths in Android Studio Preferences. See screenshots below:

[image: Flutter SDK]

[image: Dart SDK]